# How to call BaseController public function from child classes in Laravel (4)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a CustomController. For not to repeat myself, I defined getVars function in BaseController. I want to call getVars function from some functions in CustomController.

However, Laravel returns 404 error without any exception. What is wrong?

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    public function getVars($var1, $var2, $var3=Null, $var4=Null) {
        return [];
    }
}

class CustomController extends BaseController {
    public function doBla1($var1, $var2) {
        $vars = $this->getVars();
    }
    public function doBla2() {
        $vars = $this->getVars();
    }
    public function doBla3() {
        $vars = $this->getVars();
    }
}
```

Sorry :( I found the reason of error. The names of doBla1 and getVars functions are same. This results in a 404 error. Sorry :(

Comment: put your routes

Comment: I didn't add any route for this. Should I?

Comment: how you will test your controller without routes? 404 will popup when you request a route that doesn't exit, also you need to make `$var1` and `$var2` = null

Comment: I call a function from child class. This is not about routes. I think laravel just doesn't give the reason of the error.

Comment: i mean, provide us with full scenario, also with a snippet from the exception (404 is an exception)

Comment: Sorry :( I found the reason of error. The names of doBla1 and getVars functions are same. This results in a 404 error. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is useful when you have method/function defined in same controller.

For functions inside parent controller you can use

```
Parent::getVars($var1, $var2)
```